# Proper way to terminate a thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm learning about multithreading and I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

int distance = 20;
int distanceCovered = 0;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mu;

void keep_moving(){
  while(true){
  std::cout << "Distance is: " << distanceCovered << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
  distanceCovered++;
  if(distanceCovered == distance){
    cv.notify_one();
    std::terminate();
   }
 }
}

void wake_me_up()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mu);
  cv.wait( ul, []{ return distanceCovered==distance; });   // protects the lines of code below
  std::cout << "I'm here" << std::endl;
  std::terminate();
}

int main() {
  std::thread driver(keep_moving);
  std::thread wake_me(wake_me_up);
  driver.join();
  wake_me.join();

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see thread 'keep_moving' counts from 0-20 in 20 seconds and then notifies the 'wake_me_up' thread which prints "I'm here" and then terminates. After notifying the thread the 'keep_moving' thread also terminates.

Please tell me if I'm terminating the threads in a proper way. When I run this code I get the following message:

```
terminate called without an active exception
I'm here
terminate called recursively
Aborted
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you should be calling [`std::terminate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/terminate/)? Because you **really** shouldn't be.

Comment: Rob K because my program counts from 1-20 and then I wanted second thread to print "I'm here" then be done. But instead after that happens thread1 keeps incrementing that value from 20 to infinity. It was my impression that after main function finishes both threads go 'out of scope' so to say :). But apparently I have not understood it properly. Is there any way of achieving what I want without doing something which is not recommended?

Answer (score 21):

No. The correct (and only correct in standard C++) way to terminate a thread is to return from its thread function.

`std::terminate` kills your entire process. Even if it only killed the current thread (i.e. behaved like the Win32 `TerminateThread` function, *which you should **never** call*!), it would not unwind the stack, not call destructors, and thus possibly leave some necessary cleanup unfinished (like releasing mutexes).

`std::terminate` is meant to be used on a critical failure where your program cannot possibly continue. The message "without an active exception" is because the primary use of `terminate` is to kill the program if the exception system fails, e.g. due to a nested exception, so the function by default looks for an active exception and prints information about it.

Comment: @AndyG No you can't. [terminate.handler] says: "Required behavior:
A terminate_handler shall terminate execution of the program without returning to the caller". If your terminate handler doesn't kill your program, your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: But wouldn't you be able to do some stuff in the terminate handler?

Comment: @PasserBy Yes. You can do stuff. And then you have to stop execution of the process somehow. You can call `std::abort` or `ExitProcess` or even `exec` if you want to, but the process must not continue. Well, if you're on a system without processes, you could decide to enter an infinite "blinking warning LED" loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My program was counting from 0 to 20 and then printing "I'm here" and then continued to count from 20 to infinity. I wanted the program to stop after it reached '20' and printed 'I'm here' that's why I used terminate. How should I do it instead?

Comment: Just `return;` will do.